# On back button how can i show default option value?

Tags: jquery

```
<select>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

want to show like this after clicking on back button.

Comment: Use `selected` attribute to set default option.

Comment: i have tried so many time but its not working.

Comment: Which was default option value? And put your try code so we can better understand.

Answer (score 1):

`selected` attribute should work for you, unless you're not doing anything in your js.

```
<select>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2" selected>2</option>
</select>
```